# Thin server issue on 64 bit Ubuntu(Amazon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, thin

I have just pushed my app(rails) on ubuntu 64 bit server and have used thin and nginx.

After just two minutes after starting the thin server I am getting the issue:-

```
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
>> Exiting!
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:578:in `write_nonblock': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:578:in `eventable_write'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:368:in `block in crank_selectables'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:368:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:368:in `crank_selectables'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:324:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:318:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:318:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:62:in `run_machine'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails-3.2.8/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please help me. Don't think it is because of traffic or network congestion.Also want to ask what does broken pipe mean.

Comment: Are you sending traffic to your server? It looks like something is happening asynchronously that is causing your app to crash.

Comment: @Rico ..I am looking at the question and thinking the same..But what kind of traffic can cause an app to go down in 2 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct file and folder permissions set up for logging and the app?  Seems like a potential write-lock/fail.

Comment: @StuartB..I had given 777 permissions to the entire folder..What else should I do..Can you please suggest me something